# Clutch pedal has a step?

Tags: clutch, manual-transmission, mitsubishi, lancer

The vehicle is a 1993 Lancer Evo

idk how to explain this but my clutch pedal sorta has 2 positions? When I press it with little force it stops and I can engage gears. It's a little tough though and a little grindy (especially reverse). Now if I press it with little force and it stops and THEN I apply more force it goes all the way in and all gears engage perfectly with very little force required.

Here's a demonstration:
https://youtu.be/HX51kO6NxJM

In the video you can hear the car shaking and my seat belt buckle squeaking (lol) while in gear (00:03). But when I press the pedal with a lot of force applied it doesn't do that in gear (00:08)
Also at 00:42 you can see me press the pedal forcefully all the way in and put it in gear, then let out the pedal to the "step" point and the engine barely drops RPM. In comparison when I press the pedal in with little force and try let it out a little bit the engine drops RPM significantly and the car starts shaking again (00:37)

All this is done while car is parked and parking brake applied

I hope it's not a bearing or fork issue. Maybe low fluid or air in system?

Comment: What is the year/make/model/engine of the vehicle in question? Is this new behavior?

Comment: 1993 Lancer Evo. Behavior is not new but I didn't care about this before

Comment: Update: checked the clutch reservoir and the fluid level is at the min mark and also it is somewhat dark. Should I try just adding fluid to the reservoir? Also one more thing, I can't get the clutch pedal past the first point when the engine is not running

Comment: Having fluid up to max level would be a good thing. No clue why you wouldn't be able to depress the clutch pedal with engine not running. Behavior should be the same either way. I will say, when you are at the first point, w/ transmission in gear and engine running, you can hear what sounds like the friction disk sliding on the pressure plate and flywheel. This isn't a good thing to allow to happen. Also, when you're forcing it into gear at this point, you're also putting a lot of wear on your synchros, which is wearing out your transmission. Only shift gears with the pedal fully depressed.

Comment: Are you talking about the squeaking sound? It's the seat buckle metal part rubbing against console. It's busted and always rattles so I have to drive with passanger seat belt buckled all the time

Comment: I don't think that's what I'm hearing. Right after you force it in gear (with pedal at the "first stop"), I hear a scraping noise which continues until you either take it out of gear or push the pedal to the floor. It is a very distinctive noise to me which indicates as I've stated.

Comment: Also, I didn't mention, but that first "step" you talk about seems to be the point at which the throw-out bearing has reached the clutch fingers to start disengaging the clutch. This is a normal thing for every manually shifted car, the difference being where that point is at. Most vehicles I've driven this point is about at an inch (~3cm) worth of pedal travel, not 1/2 way down (or however far yours is traveling).

Comment: I don't think I'm hearing the plate scraping sound from the video. I'll try out tommorow in person and try to do something with the buckle so I can hear better. And also fill up the clutch reservoir. Not really used to hydraulic clutch systems as I only have driven motorcycles and Subarus before

Comment: Update 2: Today I topped off the reservoir to the max line and also recorded clutch actutor from down below. https://youtube.com/shorts/hX14JMZOi1s?feature=share
First I try to push the clutch with engine off. I guess it does go all the way in, it just feels more difficult when unassisted? So I then start the engine and try to demonstrate the "lip". I feel like it's easier now after adding clutch juice but still the lip is feelable and inconvinient. I'll try to bleed/flush the system this weekend.

Comment: Update 3: Flushed the clutch system, it  idn't do nothing. Probably busted pressure plate or bearing

Answer (score 0):

My first thought on this is that they’re may be an air bubble in the hydraulic system.  The first movement may be air being compressed, then the final movement is the clutch being released.

I would pump fresh fluid through the system and try to remove any air.

Answer (score 0):

After your second video (the YouTube short), if the squeak you're talking about is very audible when the car is off, then that is either the pivot on the clutch fork (what engages the throwout bearing) or it's pressure plate as it is being articulated. Depending on how many miles are on this clutch, I'd suggest it's the latter.

If you take a look at the second video and not the position of the clutch fork end within the area it can traverse (there is a rubber grommet over it to keep the dirt out), you'll notice it is very close to the "disengaged" side of things. ("Disengaged" meaning the to the side where the clutch disengages and allows the engine to spin free.) To me, this should be a lot closer to center of the hole or even closer to the other side. This indicates to me there is probably friction disk material wear. I think that is why you are getting further clutch pedal travel before the throwout bearing makes contact with the clutch fingers.

Bottom line is, I think your clutch is about worn out and needs replacement. If this is a newer clutch, then I'm probably all out in  the breeze.